# PHP Does a colon : in an array key have any special significance?

Tags: php, arrays

Q: Does a colon `:` in an array key have any special significance?

From the manual:

An array can be created by the `array()` language construct. It takes as parameters any number of comma-separated key => value pairs.

```
array(  key =>  value
     , ...
     )
```

While I was investigating what the Exception Object is set to, I created an error condition and put this line in-

```
print_r($ex);
```

Then in the web page produced looked at the source and it produces output like this-

```
Exception Object

(

[message:protected] => DB connection error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

[string:Exception:private] =>
```

Is the colon `:` in `[message:protected]` significant or is the key to the key => value pair literally `message:protected` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is `print_r`s representation of the exception object's properties. These aren't accessible with array notation unless the class implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and the property is public.

As a further note, if you had an array like this...

```
$array = array(
    'my:key' => 'my:value'
);
```

... you can access the value as you normally would with `$array['my:key']`

Answer (score 5):

`$ex` is not an array but rather an object. This is how `print_r` is printing it, indicating with `:protected` that the `message` field is marked as `protected` in the `Exception` class.

The colon doesn't have any special meaning in the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

`$ex` is **not** an array, it is an object. Objects are more complicated data structures than arrays. What you see is a textual representation of the state of this object.

The developers decided to use a similar representation as it is used for arrays, and they use the colon separation for giving further information about the attributes of the object.

The colon has no meaning, and you won't be able to access a field with e.g. `$ex['message:protected'].`